# use group by max() twice in another column

Tags: mysql, max

I use mysql query.

I want to know the date and amount of the highest salary.

I want to know if I can use max() twice as below.

The result comes out exactly as I want.

But as far as I know, you have to use only one max().

Was I mistaken?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8db0c17/4

```
create table test ( mid bigint , sal bigint ,  dt date);
insert into test values( 1, 100, '2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 
( 1, 200, '2020-02-01 00:00:00'), 
( 2, 100, '2020-03-01 00:00:00'), 
( 2, 200, '2020-04-01 00:00:00'),
( 2, 300, '2020-05-01 00:00:00'),
( 3, 500, '2020-10-01 00:00:00');

select mid, max(sal), max(dt) from test group by mid;
```

```
mid max(sal)    max(dt)
1   200         2020-02-01
2   300         2020-05-01
3   500         2020-10-01
```

Comment: No, I doubt that is what you want. In your example data make the highest salary not on the latest date. Then see if the result is still what you want. Is this still corrent: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22575b/1

Comment: Your query is legal Your two MAX are independent. The only point which must be taken into account - these two maximal values (for salary and for date) may be taken from 2 different rows. *as far as I know, you have to use only one max().* They cannot be nested - that is true.

Comment: @juergend oh. my mistake. This was not the result I wanted.

Comment: Do you need the salary which matches maximal (last) data? Or backward? If so or similar then clarify your need, and specify precise MySQL version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` several times in your query, but in your case, you will not get what you want.

If we change your data like this:

```
1, 100, 2020-01-01
1, 200, 2020-02-01
2, 100, 2020-02-01
2, 300, 2020-03-01
2, 200, 2020-04-01
2, 300, 2020-05-01
3, 500, 2020-10-01
3, 300, 2020-11-01
```

Your result will be:

```
1, 200, 2020-02-01
2, 300, 2020-05-01
3, 500, 2020-11-01
```

As you can see, for 3rd row we get maximum value for `sal` and for `dt` but separately.

We can use somthing like this to get the right result:

```
select 
 t.mid, max(t.dt), tmp.sal_max 
from test t
 join (
  select t1.mid, max(t1.sal) as sal_max
  from test t1
  group by t1.mid) tmp on tmp.mid = t.mid AND tmp.sal_max = t.sal
group by tmp.mid;
```

Result:

```
1, 2020-02-01, 200
2, 2020-05-01, 300
3, 2020-10-01, 500
```

I think it is not the simplest option, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `max` many times it should be different columns names

The other column should be in `group by`

Comment: *it should be different columns names* why? I can easily do `SELECT MAX(id) id1, MAX(id) id2 ...`.

Comment: it will work there is no use in this.
why do you want two same columns with same data

Comment: *there is no use in this* This may make sense in recursive CTE, for example. In recursive part the values may differ, but starting values are the same.

Comment: OK fine yes in few case it will be help full.